# Cut words from files based on grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cut

I have a small bash script as follows :

```
cat foo.txt | grep "balt" > bar_file
```

Ideally what I would like to happen is that every word that contains `"balt"`, I would like removed from the `foo.txt` file. Can I get direction on how to basically move words from one file from another based on whats grepped.

Comment: so you want to remove any word that contains "balt" and transfer the rest to another file?

Comment: From the foo.txt file if the word contains "balt" I'd like to remove it from that file and paste entire word in another (new) file. @ritesht93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side note: There is no need to use `cat` and pipe its output to `grep` since you can pass the filename directly to `grep` which reduces a single process execution.

As for your question you can `-o` option of `grep` to get matching words only having `balt` in them along with `\b` boundary checking like this:

```
$ cat foo.txt 
abcd baltabcd xyz
xdef abbaltcd xyz
balt
$ grep -o '\b\w*balt\w*\b' foo.txt 
baltabcd
abbaltcd
balt
$ grep -o '\b\w*balt\w*\b' foo.txt > bar_file
$ cat bar_file 
baltabcd
abbaltcd
balt
$
```

As you can see grep matches 0  or more word characters present before or after `balt` and puts that into another file.
Example words were: `baltabcd`, `abbaltcd` and `balt`

Comment: can use `-w` option to avoid using `\b`

Comment: @Sundeep well yes .. that could be an alternative too